# Why the image can't pop up with jquery lightbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

I want to add `lightbox2` from  `http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/` to my page, following their how to use.add the right js file and css file.but it doesn't work.
i fell all my opertion is right, but when i click the image it can't pop up?what's wrong with it.

#### [Issue Demo](http://down123.xxmn.com/wemade/taxonomy/term/4)

Comment: Not sure about the exact reason for a down-vote, but not everyone likes to have to go look at an external site when attempting to help. Perhaps you could append some of your markup to your question?

Comment: I imagine it's because your question is too vague... You are basically saying "look at my website, fix it". You should try to give a more clear indication of what it is you have tried and what you have discovered... Your issue is with this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'` find the source of that -> issue solved :)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your version of jQuery is out of date: **1.4.4**. The version of Lightbox you're using is trying to call `on()`. You need at least version **1.7** to use `on()`.

Comment: if i want to use 1.44 ,is there a function equals on()?

Comment: You need to **not** use version 1.4.4 - its not actively supported anymore. You could, however, probably modify a local version of Lightbox to use `live()`, though it's not 100% equivalent.

Comment: i am sorry i change to live() it still can't work

Comment: Sorry, the answer to your problem is to update your version of jQuery or look for an older version of Lightbox2. Anything else is kludge and should be avoided.